# sp_helpdb -- returns nothing, because db is restoring (log shipping target) SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can I see where the db files live, etc?

e.g. sp_helpdb output when sp_helpdb itself won't give results because db is in restoring state.

This is SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see where the database files are you can use the [sys.master_files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx) dmv.